# PlayStation 2 game development on any console?

Tags: sdk, playstation

I'm interested in creating software/games for Sony PlayStation 2 consoles since they contain **powerful** processors for graphics (GPUs), floating-point calculations and general CPU.

I have acquired a **PS2 console** and its **PS2 SDK v3.07** which, supposedly came with the PS2 Dev Kit (which costs $8,000). I don't have the **PS2 Dev Kit console** though.

Can I use my **ordinary PS2 console, to develop native programs and games?** Will I require that special PS2 which comes with the PS2 Dev Kit or can I re-program my PS2 to behave that way? I don't mind lack of debugging features as long as I can **write code** and **get it to run** on the PS2!

Also, is the PS2 supplied with the PS2 Dev Kit a special one with extra/**different hardware?** Or just a **different OS** in order to have debugging facilities etc?

Here's whats I got in the PS2 SDK:

- PlayStation 2 Programmer Tool Tool Chain EE 3.2-ee-030926
- PlayStation 2 Programmer Tool Runtime Library Release 3.0.2
- PlayStation 2 Programmer Tool Runtime Library NTGUI package Release 3.0
- PlayStation 2 CD/DVD-Rom Generator 1.5
- PlayStation 2 CD/DVD-Rom Generator 2.0
- ProDG for PlayStation 2
- License for ProDG tools (PlayStation 2)
- License for ProDG Target Manager & ProDG NDK Analyzer
- GCC ee 3.2 ee Cygwin
- Hardware Docs (eg. Instruction Set Manual, User Guide, etc)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [Linux on your PS2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_for_PlayStation_2) and then target **PS2 Linux**, similar to **Red Hat Linux 6**.

> The documentation with this Linux kit will give all the same information about the PS2 hardware that Sony provides its licensed game developers, full details on the PS2's proprietary **Emotion Engine** core instruction set, the **Graphic Synthesizer**, and the **Vector Processing Units**. ~ [Opening Up the PlayStation 2 with Linux](http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2002/03/21/linuxps2.html)

Begin at the [PlayStation 2 Developer Network](http://playstation2-linux.com/) by Sony.

Comment: No way to do what I'm asking (build for PS2 DVD), I believe, so we'll just have to make-do with building for Linux!

Answer (score 1):

I think that [this article on linuxdevcenter.com](http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2002/03/21/linuxps2.html) covers everything you are asking about and more.

Good Luck!